# Which validation rule to use for a float with Laravel 4?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have a form with two text inputs that must be floats (specifically, these text inputs are for `geographic coordinates`), looked at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#available-validation-rules) and found a rule for `integer` and `numeric` but not for `float`.

I was thinking using the "numeric" because the text inputs are disabled and the value only changes when a marker on a map is moved.

What would be the best way to validate a float?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a regular expression rule (`regex:pattern`) for this and since you want to use to validate `Geographic Coordinates` then you should use a regular expression rule because a `Geo Coord` may look something like `23.710085, 90.406966`, which is the coordinates (lat long) of `Dhaka Bangladesh` and it also may contain a coordinates like `-33.805789,151.002060`. So here is the syntax:

```
$rules = array('form_field_name' => 'required|regex:pattern' );
```

Or maybe just

```
$rules = array('form_field_name' => 'regex:pattern' );
```

So, the pattern should be something like this `/^[+-]?\d+\.\d+, ?[+-]?\d+\.\d+$/`. So, finally, it should look something like this (`pattern is copied from internet`):

```
$rules = array('form_field_name' => 'regex:/^[+-]?\d+\.\d+, ?[+-]?\d+\.\d+$/');
```

Check the [Laravel Validation (regex)](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-regex).

Comment: I think regular expressions are the next thing I'll be learning, they seem to be very useful.

Comment: @Isaias, Yes, it's really useful in some cases and glad it helped you.

Answer (score 9):

The `numeric` rule can be used for that because it uses the `is_numeric()` function to test the value. Although, normally you'd want something that uses the `is_float()` function, since form inputs are in the form or string, `is_numeric()` should be used instead. Here's a quote from the [PHP doc for is_float](http://php.net/is_float):

> To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form
>   input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

Answer (score 4):

```
        'latitude' => 'regex:/^-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6,}$/',
        'longitude' => 'regex:/^-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6,}$/',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Validator::extend('gps', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

        if (preg_match('/^-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6,}\s*,\s*-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6,}$/', $value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```